# Share WiFi signal wirelessly with sony wireless card

Tags: wireless, sharing

I run Ubuntu on a Sony Vaio that, when I used Windows, had the ability to share my WiFi with up to 5 other devices wirelessly. Is there any way to get that same functionality now or am I stuck using an ethernet cable?

Comment: Windows probably did some hackery to make it work - in Ubuntu, the concept is "One in, one out" so if your wireless is the one you're wanting to share you'd need another wireless card, I believe, to make it work (at least, out of the box)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I assume you mean you are connecting into Ubuntu via a network cable and then want to use your wireless card to serve internet to other devices, sounds like you dont have a wireless router. This can actually be done pretty easily, not sure about other versions, but definitely in 14.04 and 14.10.

1. Disable WIFI and plug in an internet cable to your laptop so that your Ubuntu is connect to a wired internet and wireless is disabled.
2. Go to Network Icon on top panel -> Edit Connections …, then click the Add button in the pop-up window.
3. Choose Wi-Fi from the drop-down menu when you’re asked to choose a connection type
4. In next window, do

   Type in a connection name. The name will be used later.
   Type in a SSID 
   Select mode: Infrastructure 
   Device MAC address: select your wireless card from drop-down menu.
5. Go to Wi-Fi Security tab, select security type WPA & WPA2 Personal and set a password.
6. Go to IPv4 Settings tab, from Method drop-down box select Shared to other computers.

When done, click the save button.

After above steps, a configuration file was created under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections directory. File name is same to the connection name you typed in step 4.

Now press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, paste the commands below and hit enter to edit the configuration file:

```
 gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-hotspot
```

Replace wifi-hotspt with the connection name you typed in step 4.

When the file opens, find out the line mode=infrastructure and change it to mode=ap. Finally save the file.

When everything’s done, enable WIFI from Network Manager icon on the panel. It should automatically connect to the hotspot you created. If not, select “Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network …” and select it from the drop-down box.

You can now connect any other device via wireless, but the Ubuntu machine will need to keep it's wired connection.

edit: Now that I think of it, you may also be able to follow a simular process using WIFI and ditch the cable. I tried a few times quickly and couldn't get it to work. But it will work with wired connection to Ubuntu, and then access wireless via other devices.